# how do I make a list into multiple lists of that list?

Tags: python, list, loops

so lets say this is my list:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

and I want it to become:

```
new_list = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

I know there's a way to do it with:

```
new_list = []
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []    
for x in my_list:
  new_list1.append((x[0]+x[1]+x[2]))
  new_list2.append((x[3]+x[4]+x[5]))
  new_list.append((new_list1+new_list2))
print(new_list)
```

is there another way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: What is the pattern of the nested lists? Each 3 elements, a new list?

Comment: @Christian yea each 3 elements

Comment: Your code does quite different things than what your example shows. What do you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [my_list[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(my_list), 3)]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: what is xrange? what is that x for?

Comment: @user3025931 let me google it for you: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Comment: @user3025931 as you seems to be using python3, use range instead